# Django django-extensions commands unavailable ( graph_models )

Tags: python, django, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to install django-extensions + graphviz + pygraph but i can't.
I have done the following steps ( under Ubuntu ):

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev graphviz-dev python-pygraphviz
```

in the project virtualenv (running python 2.7.2+):

```
source <path to virtualenv>/bin/activate
pip install django django-extensions
```

if i run

```
which python
```

it selects the python in my virtualenv, so the python i'm using is the right one.
in the virtualenv's site-package i have pygraphviz and django-extensions

```
python manage.py shell
import django_extensions
import pygraphviz 
RUNS OK
```

in my django project i have added 'django_extensions' in my INSTALLED_APPS

But when i run

```
python manage.py help
```

i can't see the commands and they are unavailable.

```
python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o model.png
Unknown command: 'graph_models'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

How can I fix this ?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Is this an existing project? i.e. does `python manage.py runserver` work ok? Just to confirm - there are no `django-extension` commands appearing when you run `python manage.py help`?

Comment: Yes i confirm, no django-extension command is shown

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Run this in manage.py shell:

```
from django.conf import settings; 'django_extensions' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
```

If it doesn't return True, then it means that you didn't add 'django_extensions' properly in INSTALLED_APPS, and that would be the only reason why Django doesn't find the command.

Comment: wouldn't `python manage.py runserver` fail if `django_extensions` wasn't properly added?

Comment: Thanks! the settings.py wasn't imported in the right way... now everything works as expected... THANK YOU!

Comment: @pastylegs i think that runserver would just do as if django_extension wasn't there at all. Thank you both for your feedback.

Comment: @jpic Yea, I must check that. Well spotted anyway

Answer (score 6):

Actually, if you look at your manage.py's code, you will notice that it sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULES according to your current site: let say "mysite.settings".
If you want your manage.py to list additional extensions (e.g. ones from django-extensions or django-evolution) then you must add your project-root's folder to your python path, if not you will only get the bascc manage.py commands.

Answer (score 3):

I had it under everything else in `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`. Moving it at the top fixed it:

From

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
]
```

TO

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_extensions',
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: That is so weird!!! Moving to the top fixed my problem too.